# java: splitting 1D array to smaller 1D arrays but containing 2D informations

Tags: java, arrays, pointers, split, element

Background:

I want to store a specific amount of elements from a main array into additional arrays. The main array is 1D but contains 2D informations. The additional arrays are 1D as well. Therefore while iterating over the main array I need to swap between the arrays to store the data correctly. Thats why it's kind of adding or appending information.

So basically I want to splitt 1D array with the 2D information into smaller 1D arrays while each contains a package of 2D information.

Shortly: Split an array into small arrays and joining certain arrays to new ones.

An example:

{ 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2 }

is splitted into

{ 1, 1 }, { 2, 2 }, { 1, 1 }, { 2, 2 }

and joined to

{ 1, 1, 1, 1 }, { 2, 2, 2, 2 }.

Possible Solution:

I can solve it iterating over the original array and calling the add method of an object that stores the new information. I add a value to the first non-initialized element of an allocated array - kinda appending the data.

The following self-explaining and simplified (like not caring about OOB errors) code shows how it could be realized.

```
public class Example{

  private byte[] array;
  private int pointer=0;

  public Example(int elements){
    array = new byte[elements]
  }

  public add(byte value) {
    array[pointer] = value;
    pointer++;
  }

}
```

And the iteration could be like this, somewhere in the code:

```
byte[] mainarray;
int width, height, sectionWidth, sectionHeight;

// setting mainarray;
// setting width, height, sectionWidth, sectionHeight

Example[] example = new Example[(width / sectionWidth) * (height / sectionHeight)];

for (int i = 0; i<mainarray.length; i++) {
  int x = i / height / sectionWidth;
  int y = i / width / sectionHeight * (width / sectionWidth);
  example[x + y].add(mainarray[i]);
}
```

Another option may be accessing the additional arrays directly with a certain key to store the value. But that means I need to calculate the right array and key on every loop which may be slower overall.

Any experiences?

Is there any better (faster / more native) way to achieve this?

Comment: why are you splitting the array? Like, is this the solution you've decided upon for a larger assignment or what? How are you splitting the "2d information" in the first array? arrays can contain only primitive types, so what's going on here?

Comment: The array itself is not splitted. It's extracting information of an array and store it in smaller arrays. The only problem is, the information is not one-dimensional like the array. It's like a sprite sheet. Your sheet has x * y sprites and the data is stored one-dimensional. This is 2D information in a 1D storage. And like splitting the sheet into it sprites is the goal I want to achieve. However, arrays can contain any data types...